# How can I get reader profiles?

Tags: non-fiction, narrative, readers, audience, queries

How can I get a reader profile for a publishing category i.e. criminal justice, social justice?

Comment: What do you mean?  It sounds like you think there's only one type of reader per broad category?  Please [edit] to clarify your question.

Comment: What's a reader profile?

Comment: Not an answer to this question, but maybe an answer to your larger problem: Just write your story.

Comment: We're not sure what your question is. If you could please clarify, we'll consider taking the question off hold.

Comment: The only thing I can think OP is looking for is acting how do they know what genre their story is in?  That is what it seems to be asking... [Reader Profile](http://www.writersdigest.com/editor-blogs/there-are-no-rules/getting-published/before-you-write-a-single-word-develop-a-reader-profile) I assume they are talking about this.... just do your own research honestly... because it depends on what YOU want... do you want it to be read by kids? do you want to tell a true story? a fantasy? These reader profiles really isn't... necessary...

Comment: Genres tend to have a general trend to who reads them, what kind of people read them, but you aren't persay tailoring the story to the reader to  know what hobbies they have.... more so.... you are writing to the genre tropes of what the expected story is for that genre.  You don't need to know the average income for people that read that general genre in order to write a fantasy story...

Comment: Reader profiles really isn't needed because that's more about Marketing your story than it is writing your story.... Most of which will be done for you by a publisher/agent.  The only time the culture of the readers may be needed is if you want to write a non-fiction or a fiction based on current events... If you want to write a story for young adults using current slang, just sit in a mall for a few days and listen to people talk.